# Can I have multiple nested forms within the same fieldset?

Tags: forms

I am building a custom module that adds a form to certain node types that allows the user to fill/save some additional information about the node.

I would like to have 2 buttons. 1 which saves the data entered (currently working) and another which posts the data to an external script.

I can get this working by creating two different forms and settings their #action's accordingly but I would like the form markup all in a single fieldset, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can have both buttons in the same form. Inside the form's #submit handler (or each button's separate #submit handler), based on which button has been used to submit the form, you can either save the data, or do a `drupal_http_request()` to execute the external script.

Your form would include buttons roughly like this:

```
'save' => array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save'),
  '#submit' => array('save_function_name'),
),
'process' => array(
  '#type' => 'submit,
  '#value' => t('Process'),
  '#submit' => array('process_function_name'),
)
```

Then, the two functions `save_function_name()` and `process_function_name()` would do the job.

Comment: Would drupal_http_request() allow me to actually open the page? I would like the user to be able to print this page also

Comment: Hm... Now I'm not quite sure how to do that. You could use drupal_goto() for redirection to a drupal path. To redirect your users to an external webpage you could use header('Location:'). But to submit a POST form, I can really only think of a separate form, which is where you are coming from...

Answer (score 1):

You can acccomplish that by calling drupal_render() and passing it the fieldset and its children.

The twitter module does this for the Drupal 6 version. See the following usage example:

```
$add_account = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Add Twitter accounts'),
  '#weight' => 5,
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  '#children' => '',
);

if (user_access('add authenticated twitter accounts')) {
  $add_account['#children'] .= drupal_get_form('twitter_auth_account_form');
}
if (twitter_connect()) {
  $add_account['#children'] .= drupal_get_form('twitter_non_auth_account_form');
}
$output .= drupal_render($add_account);
```