# How to put a custom form inside node form with own submit button?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I have a small custom form which has its own submit button.

```
$form['activity']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Execute'),
      '#name' => 'test_button',
      '#submit' => array('my_custom_form_submit')
    );
```

I placed this in the page manager in the node edit form.

But the problem is the function `my_custom_form_submit` is not get executed. Instead the node form gets submitted and redirected to node view page.

Is there any way to to execute 'my_custom_form_submit' function on clicking on the custom form submit button?

**Note**: I don't need ajax, I want it without ajax.

Answer (score 1):

you should use an ajax in inner form on submit like :

```
  $form['activity']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Execute'),
  '#name' => 'test_button',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_handle_form_submit',
    'effect' => 'fade',
),
);

 function _handle_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
 // your stuff here
 }
```

you can see ajax example modules [Ajax Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)

Comment: I don't need ajax. I want it without ajax.

Comment: then you can create custom submit handlers for both forms.. like  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8757/can-i-have-multiple-nested-forms-within-the-same-fieldset

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in submit type.

**Code** -

```
$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Execute'),
  '#name' => 'test_button',
  '#submit' => array('my_custom_form_submit')
);
```